# Karaf OSGI How to copy files as part of postProcessing?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, karaf, metatype

I have some files that I need to copy to a directory configured in the .cfg file as part of installing the bundle in Karaf server. I couldn't figure out what exactly is the js method to invoke. Below id the snippet I used to extract a jar using postProcess  in metatype.js, but how do I copy a file..

```js
var postProcess = function(group, map ) {
       if(map["destination.script.path"] && map["destination.script.path"].trim()!='') {
               scope.installTasks.expandResources(java.lang.System.getProperty('karaf.base') +"/data/hrc/install/source/resources.jar",map["destination.script.path"]+"/scripts",false,
         function(key,success)  {
       print("expanded " + success);
   },
   function(key,fail){
       print(fail.getMessage());
   });
       }
};

var success = function(source,val){
 //print(val);
}
var fail = function(source,e){
 //print(source); 
}
```

This is how my OSGI-INF looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, installTasks is an internal utility used in my project.